# camel netty4 ChannelHandlerFactory ByteToMessageDecoder error

Tags: apache-camel

as i am a beginner of camel. i wanna get a hint to solve my problem.
here is my code

full source link : https://github.com/kcy0142/camel_netty_test

```
@Configuration
public class ChannelHandlerFactoryByteArrayDecoder implements ChannelHandlerFactory {

    @Bean(name="vpaByteDecoder")
    @Qualifier("vpaByteDecoder")
    public ChannelHandler newChannelHandler() {
      return (ChannelHandler) new VpaByteDecoder();
    }
    public  class VpaByteDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder{

    }
}
```

and my router is

```
from("netty4:tcp://localhost:8004?textline=true&sync=true&decoders=#vpaByteDecoder&encoders=#stringEncoder").
```

and error is invoked like this

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: config.ChannelHandlerFactoryDecoder$VpaByteDecoder is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.
```

ByteToMessageDecoder should not sharable. so i implenmented ChannelHandlerFactory

i dont know the reason.plaease show me the way to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its the factory class that should be named not the bean method, something like this instead, and remove the `@Bean`

```
@Component(name="vpaByteDecoder")
public class ChannelHandlerFactoryByteArrayDecoder implements ChannelHandlerFactory {
```